# how to use alpha value in Java Swing RGB color?

Tags: java, swing, colors

I have this **GRB** color: 24;116;205. Its **Hex** value is 1874CD. I use it in my Swing application like this:

```
Color clr = new Color(Ox1874CD);
```

to set a panel background. It works.

Now I have to add alpha value in, **RGBA**: 24;116;205;1.

According to Java API, the alpha value is at 24-31 bit. Then its Hex value should be **01**1874CD.

```
Color clr = new Color(Ox011874CD, true);
```

is used to create the Color. But it doesn't work. The panel's background color is not the expected one. I also tried put the alpha hex value 01 at the end of Hex number. It is the same. Anybody can tell me how to correctly use this alpha value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The panel's background color is not the expected one.

Explain what you expect and what you see. We are not mind readers we don't know what you are expecting.

> Now I have to add alpha value in, RGBA: 24;116;205;1.

I think the alpha value should be 255, which means it is fully opaque. A value of 1 would mean it is (almost) fully transparent.

> According to Java API, the alpha value is at 24-31 bit. Then its Hex value should be 011874CD.

In hex the "255' would be "FF".

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. We can't execute a single line of code to see what you are seeing.

Comment: The alpha value is not from 0 to 1?

Comment: @peterboston Alpha ranges from 0x00 (completely transparent) to 0xFF (completely opaque) in the ARGB format used by new Color(int, boolean) constructor. Painting with an alpha of 0x01 will do very little or maybe nothing at all (depending on the actual color values).

Comment: @peterboston, `The alpha value is not from 0 to 1?` - did you try the suggestion? Did it work? Why don't you use the constructor where you specify the (r, g, b, a) values separately. Read the API again. It depends which constructor you use whether the values are 0 - 255, or 0,0f - 1.0f.

Comment: I read the color from properties file as one value, that is why i use the  Color(int, boolean) constructor.